# How to: draw freehand circles with shadows?

Tags: screenshot, snipping

Normally i like to draw [freehand circles on screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258295/aero-how-to-draw-solid-opaque-colors-on-glass) in order to draw the reader's attention:

[image]

But now i want to bring my freehand circles to the next level, and [include drop-shadows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775).

Normally i use [Windows Snipping Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Use-Snipping-Tool-to-capture-screen-shots), or more rarely [Zoomit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434). Is there tool that allows freehand circles with drop shadows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) can do this.

[image]